# Concurrency issue from read/write from table on multiple threads (race condition)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-models, concurrency

I am building an app where each user is assigned a task from a tasks table. In order to do so, we are going to mark an existing entry as deleted (flag) and then add an entry that holds the person responsible for the task in that table.

The issue here is that if multiple users decide to get a task at the same time, the request would prioritize older entries over newer ones, so there is the chance they are going to read the same task and get assigned the same task. Is there a simple way around it?

My first inclination was to create a singleton class that handles job distribution, but I am pretty sure that such issues can be handled by Django direct. What should I try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make sure there is no race condition in MySQL database when incrementing a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364273/how-to-make-sure-there-is-no-race-condition-in-mysql-database-when-incrementing)

Comment: @Mohamed if you use any database the run condition should be checked in databse side.